# Simulated sex scene with Joi: What was in the hooker's mouth?

Tags: blade-runner-2049

Just rewatching the scene and I see the hooker remove a small plastic thing from her mouth. Was that part of the simulation or had she stolen something from K?

Comment: Just a tangential comment: I thought this minor plot, especially the line where the replicant hooker gets in a dig (but only actually because the hologram was acting sort of mean herself) "quiet now; I've been inside of you, there's not as much there as you think" was tremendously significant. In a way, the replicant by acting jealous was paying a supreme compliment. But maybe replicants are more accepting of the personhood of things other than humans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a bug she had hidden and then planted in K's clothing so the rebels could find him.

Comment: That's right. But bizarre that she didn't just keep it in her clothes POCKET.

Comment: Yeah. Would be interesting to know what the writer or director had in mind.